# How to compare all files from two different changesets?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, version-control

In Source Explorer, there is an option for comparing two different changesets of **one single** file.

However, I would like to compare **all** files from two different changesets.

Is there a way to do so?

Or do I need to extract both versions separately into two directories and compare them side-by-side?

Answer (score 1):

You may check this tool [Diff All Files for VS2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d8d61cc9-6660-41af-b8d0-0f8403b4b39c), which can quickly and easily compare all files in a changeset, shelveset, or with pending changes in TFS to see what has changed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I installed it, but as far as I see, it can compare only during "Pending Changes". But I want to compare two completely different versions, without having to check something in. Is that possible with this tool? I don't see it in the documentation.

Comment: You are right, this tool is only available when there is Pending Changes, and compare with workspace version or latest version. It can't achieve what you want. Since you can also compare two different folder between server and local, how about get one of the changeset to local, and compare with another changeset in server?

Comment: Thank you for writing. Yes, of course I can extract a changeset, or even extract two changesets, and then compare them. I just was looking for an easier way. Maybe I will write and publish my own plug-in.

Comment: There is not a default way to compare all files from two different changesets. Custom plug-in is the only way.